# how to unit test on functions in my case

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to do unit test for a fail http request. I have something like

JS controller

```
myFactory.getName(url)
     .then(function(returnData) {                        
         console.log(returnData)  //works
      }, function() {                                          //not cover
          console.log('error')  //never get called             //not cover
          $timeout(function() {                                //not cover
             //do stuff                                        //not cover
              }, 100);                                         //not cover
      });
```

my Factory

```
factory.getName = function(url) {
        return $http.get(url);
};
```

Unit test

```
  beforeEach(module('muApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_, myFactory_) {
        scope        = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $timeout     = _$timeout_;
        $rootScope   = _$rootScope_;
        myFactory = _$myFactory_;

        myCtrl = _$controller_('myCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope
        });

        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/request/aaa').respond(404);
    }));

describe('test' , function(){
     it('should show error if request fail', function() {
            myFactory.getName('/api/request/aaa');
            $httpBackend.flush();
     });

    //Will show error but still won't cover the call back function
     it('should show error if request fail', function() {
            myFactory.getName('/api/request/aaa').then(function() {

            }, function(){
               console.log('error')  // this will show in my karma
            });
            $httpBackend.flush();
     });

})
```

I want to cover the callback error function but not sure what's wrong here. Thanks for the help!